# Unable to find the tablenames and their column names in database of ancal in android

Tags: android

We have executed **android **ancal**** application. We found that it is using sqlite database for storing the data. We need to add some more features to the **ancal** application and so we had gone through the code. But we were unable to find the **table names and column names** in that code. 
     Actually we need to add some more tables and columns to the existing database. How to know them. Please help us......

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Read the source code.

Step #2: Search the source code for the phrase "CREATE TABLE".

You will find the `CREATE TABLE` statement [here](http://code.google.com/p/ancal/source/browse/trunk/src/pl/magot/vetch/ancal/database/DataTable.java).